# Windows Phone Emulator - Virtualization Error

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, emulation, virtualization, hyper-v

I have installed Win 8.1 Pro 64 Bit in virtual box as Guest OS with Win 7 Ultimate 64 bit as Host OS. My device supports Virtualization, config is as follows:
Intel Core i7 3610QM (III Gen)
8 GB RAM

Though Coreinfo shows that virtualization is supported by my Host OS & also in Virtual Box but in Guest OS(Win 8.1) error is being shown that Virtualization is not supported.

Kindly refer to image :
[Image Link](http://goo.gl/OCVTa6)

Kindly provide me a solution to overcome this issue or any other way to run emulator. Are there any emulator like Genymotion or Bluestacks for Windows Phone.

Comment: Q: Does this not work in your Win7 host: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?  Q: Jave you considered trying VMWare instead of VBox?

Comment: It is not working on Win 7 host as it is for win 8 only. I have tried using virtual box only.

Comment: Hi - I recall the restriction about needing Win8 to run the Win8 SDK ... but I didn't realize that was a restriction for the Win8 phone emulator, too.  Sigh...  1) Your hardware needs to support [SLAT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/11/06/are-you-slat-compatible-wp8-sdk-tip-01.aspx), 2) Here's (an admittedly sketchy) article about running the SDK and emulator under VMWare: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588008/Creating-a-Virtual-Windows-Phone-8-Development-Env, 3) Finally, this suggests you *cannot* do it with VBox: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=55070

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using VMWare instead of Virtual Box. It is not possible to do using Virtual Box as suggested by [@FoggyDay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3135317/foggyday) https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=55070